# Convert PHP Explode String to AS3

Tags: php, actionscript-3

How to convert this form PHP to AS3?

```
$arr = explode(" | ", $str);
foreach($arr as $item)
{
    $arr2 = explode(": ", $item);
    $finalArray[$arr2[0]] = $arr2[1];
}
```

The function is to turn this string into an array:

> Title: Murk | Tags: Hello | Nachr:
>   Lorem | Quelle: Ipsum |

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't be an associative array, but you can do this with an Object. Something like:

```
var str:String = "Title: Murk | Tags: Hello | Nachr: Lorem | Quelle: Ipsum";
var arr:Array = str.split(" | ");
var obj:Object = new Object();
for each (var s:String in arr) {
    var a:Array = s.split(": ");
    obj[a[0]] = a[1];
}

trace(obj.Title); // Murk
```